# Can a black hole in a quasi-de Sitter universe have scalar hair?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, klein-gordon-equation, de-sitter-spacetime, no-hair-theorem

Any static and axially symmetric, asymptotically flat black hole spacetime cannot support scalar hair.

The universe is not asymptotically flat since it is quasi-de Sitter. Could we find a black hole with scalar hair in quasi-de Sitter Universes?

Answer (score 1):

I may not grasp what you're exactly asking, but in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0205319) an asymptotically de Sitter black hole with scalar hair is reported.

The scalar field of this theory dresses the black hole spacetime with a secondary scalar hair since the parameter that determines its behavior is the black hole mass, and there is no way to turn off the mass without turning off the scalar field.

However, gravitationally the scalar field is undetectable, since this spacetime does not differ from an extreme asymptotically de Sitter Reisser-Nordstrom black hole.

Comment: I am just asking if black holes inside a dS Universe (or almost dS as it seems to us) could have black holes with scalar hair. I presume the dS Universe as a whole CAN, but I am not sure if the interior of dS where we live in can sustain BH with scalar charges since, as we presume, scalar charges live on the boundary of the BH/Universe, don't they?